# Can travis-ci run docker?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am unable to run a docker container in a Travis continuous integration job.

https://travis-ci.org/buildbot/buildbot/builds/36547150

```
pkg/installation_tests/testall.sh
Segmentation Fault or Critical Error encountered. Dumping core and aborting.
pkg/installation_tests/testall.sh: line 16:  7343 Aborted                 docker build $dir
make: *** [docker_install_tests] Error 1
```

My guess is that there are missing kernel stuff in the travis workers, but it is difficult to tell.

Answer (score 14):

As of August 2015, [Travis CI officially supports Docker](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-08-19-using-docker-on-travis-ci/).

See [Using Docker in Builds](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) for usage details.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, while we currently support Docker as an alternative virtualization platform, we don't directly support running Docker inside of the current setup, at least directly.

However, there are workarounds that could help you there from the fine folks at Docker themselves: https://github.com/jpetazzo/sekexe

Comment: Just a quick follow-up to my own answer here, we now officially support Docker: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-08-19-using-docker-on-travis-ci/

Answer (score 7):

In case you have not yet solved the problem yourself, here https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/56cb59cc262e9d2c02f9e11cfacab65f0b659c5f/.travis.yml#L10-L24 you can find a practical example of the solution suggested above.