# how to run Docker in Travis hosted in travis-ci.com

Tags: docker, travis-ci, docker-compose

I am trying to run some tests in Travis CI using Docker (and docker-compose). 
A search on "run docker in Travis" does yield several how-to-do results, but none of these seem to be running remotely on Travis CI (travis-ci.com), instead I assume are on local Travis. 
The answers to the closest question I found, [Can travis-ci run docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098531/can-travis-ci-run-docker) , have not helped me so far.

The problem I encounter is that [Travis CI runs Ubuntu 12.04](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments) on an outdated kernel and [installing Docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#for-precise-1204-lts) requires updating the kernel and rebooting - but 'sudo reboot' will cause the virtual machine to be destroyed and leads to an infinite cycle of [install kernel -> reboot -> install_kernel ...]

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to drop in a quick note that Docker support for Travis CI is now official: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-08-19-using-docker-on-travis-ci/

It's support Docker and Docker-compose.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/moul/travis-docker claims support for Docker in Travis. It apparently uses User Mode Linux to achieve this. I haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score -1):

I know it does not help you with travis-ci but I build my docker image on circle-ci. Also Circle-CI just upgraded to docker 1.6.2.

My build file can be found here:
https://github.com/blacklabelops/jenkins/blob/master/circle.yml